# Get access to instance attributes inside of instance method

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to extend a Object and add some custom instance methods to it. How do I access data in attributes?

```
const Media = Parse.Object.extend('Media', {
  getUrl: function getUrl() {
    // HOW DO I ACCESS ATTRIBUTES HERE?
  },
});

const url = new Media({
  url: 'url here',
}).getUrl()
```

I basically expected attribute values to live either in this or in this.get('url')

So how do I get access to attributes inside of instance method?

Thanks

Comment: Do you see any issue with `return this.url` in your getUrl() definition ?

Comment: Yes, it's undefined. **this** is an empty object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I tried to execute `getUrl()` method on a nested object, however I didn't included this object in query.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that you're trying to use a constructor which doesn't initialize your instance.

```
const url = new Media({
  url: 'url here',
});
```

Here you're passing a `state object` with `url` property to `Media` constructor but you are not actually capturing that object to initialize your instance, so the object is simply ignored. Hence there's no property by the name `url` on your instance and `this.url` will be `undefined`.

As documented [here](https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_extend), `Parse.Object.extend()` will return a subclass of `Parse.Object` for the given class name. The second argument to `extend()` is an object containing instance properties/methods which are available to all the instances. Once you defined the class, you can create a new instance using the `new` keyword. If you have several parameters to initialize while creating the instance, you can make use of the `initialize` method like below.

```
const Media = Parse.Object.extend('Media', {
  initialize : function(state){
     this.url = state.url;
     this.type = state.type;
  },
  getUrl: function getUrl() {
    return this.url;
  },
  getType : function(){
    return this.type;
  }
});
```

Then create a instance by calling the constructor new keyword and passing the state object like below

```
const url = new Media({
  'url' : 'myURL',
  'type' : 'video'
});

url.getType(); // returns 'video'
url.getUrl(); // returns 'myURL'
```

Comment: This actually makes some sense, although this behaviour is not very intuitive. Btw, it seems like Parse generates some kind of cache for objects. I removed method from model, but it still was available.

Comment: `I removed method from model, but it still was available`. I didn't understand this part. Care to elaborate :)

Comment: Sorry for poor explanation :) So I removed method **getUrl()** from instance methods, but it still was available to call.

Comment: Strange. I just tried deleting `getUrl()` from instance methods and `url.getUrl();` throws an error for me. Anyways I can't comment on the issue unless I some actual code.

Comment: Hmm, that very weird. I'll try to do some more testing